# How does anchor test work?

Tags: anchor

new to solana. I have a project called day2. I have run anchor build in day2 and all it does is print integers. The command anchor build creates a json file day2.json in file day2/target/idl. However, when I run anchor test, it is looking for a day_2.json. When I renamed the json file from day2 to day_2, it works but I don't think I should be doing this for every build. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Anchor has all sorts of quirks, this might be one of them. I've had similar issues when using project names that contained numbers.

Comment: I'd search or open an issue about it over at: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues

Comment: This most likely has to do with Anchor's snake_case and camelCase conversions at various points in the build/test processes. I believe this is being actively investigated, although here is a related issue: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2058